# Adding to Loaded DOMDoc XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, flash

I'm trying to load an XML file from PHP (which I can do), and then append data to it that PHP receives from Flash. I want to add in an int (`$exists`; this is either 1 or 0), as a child of `<data>`

XML (currently):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <presets>
    <colors>0xff0000</colors>
    <colors>0x00ff00</colors>
    <colors>0x0000ff</colors>
  </presets>
</data>
```

PHP:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load("testXML.xml");
$existBool = $xml->createElement("exists", $exists);
$data->appendChild($existBool);
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

XML (desired):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <presets>
    <colors>0xff0000</colors>
    <colors>0x00ff00</colors>
    <colors>0x0000ff</colors>
  </presets>
  <exists>$exists</exists>
</data>
```

Flash:

```
var newXML:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
trace(newXML);
```

I'm getting an Unhandled IO error in Flash. Do I have to somehow let PHP know that `<data>` is part of the xml file being loaded, and not just some variable I'm declaring?

If this isn't possible to do with DOMDoc, is it possible with SimpleXMLElement (or something similar)?

**Solved.**

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I set the `data` element to the root element:

```
$data = $xml->documentElement;
```

Comment: Good job, have a cookie :)